# Считывание переменных из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть текстовый файл с некоторым кол-вом аккаунтов в виде login:password, как их можно считывать в две разных переменных?
Использовал такой метод:

```
f = open('text.txt')
for line in f:
    login = ''
    password = ''
    temp = False
    for i in range(0,len(line)):
        if line[i] != ':' and temp == False:
            login = login+line[i]
        elif temp == True:
            password = password+line[i]
        else:
            temp = True
    print(f'"{login} - {password}"')
```

Но я не уверен, что это правильный способ, и есть ли более оптимизированный способ?

Comment: Очень просто это можно сделать. Это довольно тривиальная задача. Наверняка, если вы попытаетесь сами ее решить. у вас быстро всё получится.

Comment: Забыл добавить пример своего кода, извиняюсь

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
with open("lp.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        login, password = line.strip().split(":")
        print(f"login: {login}, password: {password}")
```

Answer (score 3):

можно чуть поменьше кода.
`f.read().splitlines()` разбивает файл на строки. В итоге вы получаете список строк.

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for el in f.read().splitlines():
        login , pswd = el.split(':')
        print(login , pswd)
```